# Run All PowerShell Scripts In A Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a series of ps1 files in a directory, all of which have different names. I am trying to run them one after another with `Start-Process` and the `-Wait` parameter. How does loop through all the files in a directory and run one PowerShell script after another? There are no subfolders, and no files that are not of type ps1.

Here is my start:

```
$DirectoryList = Get-Content -Path C:\test
foreach ($Directory in $DirectoryList) {
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList ('"{0}\How To Read Me.ps1" -Path "{1}"' -f $PSScriptRoot, $Directory);
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could simply use the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\test' | ForEach-Object {
  & $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Ansgars answer does the trick but I just wanna point out (obvious to some but certainly not all) that it's quite frickin' important to have full control of the path and everything in it before looping through and executing every single file within so no harmful code is being executed.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem  | % {  & $_.FullName }` That will run everything in your current directory.

Comment: Here's even shorter :)

`gci | %{$_.FullName}`

Comment: @DevinStokes The ampersand is not optional. And the shortest possible version (without defining custom functions/aliases) is `ls|%{&$_.FullName}`.