# Bring in a directory of scripts, and run a specific function wtih powershell

Tags: powershell

TLDR: I can import a directory of scripts, store them in a variable, and run them with no functions. But I cannot run a specific function inside the imported script. Is there a Way I can run functions using this method?

I am working on a project that will be importing a directory that will have scripts added and removed on a regular basis. I would like to have the ability to 
be able to bring in that directory and run specific functions from said scripts.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851292/run-all-powershell-scripts-in-a-directory) helped me with most of it, but I can not get the imported scripts to run a function. While I could dot import each script at the top, I do not want to modify the main script if I can help it.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Or is there a better way to preform this action that I am aware of?

Below are the scripts that I have been playing with.

Main script:

```
$test = Get-ChildItem 'Path\to\script\directory' 

#I tried to dot import, will run but not actually import it.
#Nothing happens
. "Path\to\script\directory$($test[0])"

#term not recognized error
& $($test[0])

#will run, and will print to screen.
. "Path\to\script\directory$($test[1])"
```

script 0 in array:

```
function add-one()
{
    write-host "add one"
}

function add-two()
{
    write-host "add two"
}
```

script 1 in array:

```
write-host "add three"
```

Comment: I'm not real clear on your issue. If there is a function in a script then you dot source that script, the function is then available in your environment. Period.

Comment: Also `[$0]` does not make sense.

Comment: I also don't think this path `"Path\to\script\directory$($test[$1])"` would be what you think it is.

Comment: The idea is that the scripts I am going to be running will be changing. So because of this I would like to avoid hard coding dot sources. In other words, have the ability to dynamically change the scripts being ran. The extra '[$]' was a mistake on the copy over.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a module for your functions? Just `ipmo MyModule` and all functions are available...

Comment: `ls \path\to\scripts\*.ps1 | %{. $_}` That will dot source every ps1 file in a folder.

Comment: @JamesC. because I initially thought that modules could only be one script per module. Which after a quick google search shows that is not the case. I have no experience with modules, but no better time to learn then the present.

Comment: @EBGreen. I will also play around with that since I am still curious if it can be done this way.

Comment: Here's a good blog post on [Powershell module building basics](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-05-27-Powershell-module-building-basics/).